# Execute something after call an Activity extends PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

When the user call a "Configuration" ítem of the app's menu and get back to the Main activity I want to execute something else ... I guess, I have to use startActivityForResult function correct?, but I have one question, the second Activity(PreferenceActivity / Configuration) does not has a "OK" or "CANCEL" button, so Where I have to put the finish() function to return to main activity ?, only the user get back to the main Activity when press back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onBackPressed() nad use setResult(...) method in second Activity

Comment: Hi snachmsm .... I have gotten an "error" when press back...11-26 10:49:18.842: W/KeyCharacterMap(8635): Can't open keycharmap file
11-26 10:49:18.842: W/KeyCharacterMap(8635): Error loading keycharmap file '/data/usr/keychars/cyttsp3-i2c.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65536.devname='cyttsp3-i2c'      and never return to the first activity